# Not able to list the available files present in the file path in android

Tags: android

I am not able to get the list of files from this code. It throws null pointer on files. Please help to find the issue. I can see the target path in the toast as well. what am I missing here.

Thanks in Advance.

Stacktrace :

```
01-21 10:30:12.301: D/Debug(18384): /storage/emulated/0/test
01-21 10:30:12.301: D/Debug(18384): Already present
01-21 10:30:12.301: D/Debug(18384): No list/storage/emulated/0/test
```

Code used :

```
    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test";
     Log.d("Debug",targetPath);   
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
    if(targetPath!=null)
    {
        if(!targetDirector.exists())
            {
                targetDirector.mkdir();
                Log.d("DIRECtory","Created");
            }
        else
            Log.d("Debug", "Already present");
    }
    // Added these lines to debug 
    if(targetDirector!=null)
        Log.d("Size","Size = "+targetDirector.listFiles().length); //App crashes here inside if
    else
        Log.d("TargetDir", "TargetDir is null");
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    if(files!=null)
        {
            for (File file : files){
                myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    else
    {
        Log.d("Debug","No list"+targetDirector);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: At which line you are getting NPE? Post your stacktrace.

Comment: if(files!=null) I am getting files as null. You can see the log msg printed w.r.t code

Comment: Print size of `files` in Log and check your directory path. Is it right or not?? Also have you added read and write external storage permission to your manifest file?

Comment: Yea, That is what seems to be missing :)

Comment: So is it working now???

Comment: No, its throwing null pointer on targetDirector

Comment: Code is working, I missed the permission in android manifest, I don't know , earlier it used to throw error in logcat if any permission required is not mentioned, this time it was not throwing.... Thanks for mentioning the permission part. And I was just able to create a Directory without permission, whose physical presence was not there. Seems a bug in the SDK

Comment: This is because you didn't clean your project.

Comment: thanks you saved my day @Piyush